# Is there a way to implement firebase invites(SMS) without Google Sign-In for iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-invites

According to the firebase documentation, they mentioned that Google Sign-In is required to send invites. I assume they are using Google Sign-In to map with local contacts and display a custom screen for sending invites. Can I just create the custom invite link and send it using messageController on iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build a custom invite without Google Sign-In using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/)

Comment: I was thinking on the same lines. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How would you go about creating this? I was thinking about creating a custom dynamic link every time the user taps on an "Invite people" button. Is this possible?

Comment: You can generate the  invite link once .It can be during First App open or Firebase new user creation